# How to convert 2 properties of every record in a List from string to int(by extracting numbers from string) C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Currently, I have a List of objects. Each record has three properties.
    HEID = string type,(The string always looks like 12R,27L,36)
    LEID = string type,(The string always looks like 12R,27L,36)(I want to 
        extract the numbers and set them as an int.)
    RunwayId = int,

I want to take the HEId and LEId strings, and extract the numbers, and store it as a new List, or change the current properties to int type with converted values.

I am looping through the list, and this is where I want to convert each record's string type property to int type.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please add your code and [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you tried with a regular expression ?
(\d.*)R,(\d.*)L,(\d.*)

https://regex101.com/r/oETtpZ/1

Comment: @Mostafa ELite answer is a good answer, but if you provide more information about your problem we may help you with more solution, like a faster way if that what you need or your string value may contain none decimal character and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourList.Select(obj => new { HEID = float.Parse(obj.HEID), LEID = float.Parse(obj.LEID) });
```

this will return an IEnuramble of anonymous objects

you can also create new type with these properties as int and instead of selecting an anonymous type u can cast or select to the new type

```
yourList.Select(obj => new NewTypeWithInt { HEID = float.Parse(obj.HEID), LEID = float.Parse(obj.LEID) });
```

or even cleaner you can create a cast opreator

```
yourList.Select(obj => (NewTypeWithInt)obj);
```